# Al agregar una página php a otra con require no se aplican los estilos a la página agregada

Tags: php, css, estilos

Estoy realizando una página web por módulos o componentes.
Tengo una carpeta llamada partials en donde guardo diferentes componentes como un header, un menú de navegación, un footer, un carrousel, etc.
Y tengo otra carpeta llamada pages donde guardo las páginas, como index, about o contact.

La idea es que si, por ejemplo, en el index quiero poner un menú de navegación, un header, un par de textos y un footer, haga lo siguiente en él:

```
require '../partials/header.php'
require '../partials/nav.php'
<p>texto 1</p>
<p>texto 2</p>
require '../partials/footer.php'
```

De esta forma evito repetir mucho código en cada página que requiera de uno de esos componentes.

Y al hacerlo así funciona, se me cargan los contenidos, tengo el header, el menú de navegación, los textos y el footer, pero a esos componentes que he cargado no se les aplican los estilos css.
Da igual que los estilos los ponga en el documento original del componente, que en la página que los contendrá, que en ambos. Los estilos no se me aplican en ningún caso.

¿Alguien sabe por qué los estilos css no se aplican a las páginas que cargas con un require desde otra página, y qué puedo hacer para que sí los cargue?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Has mirado si realmente te está cargando los archivos css? Puede ser que por algún problema de rutas no te esté cargando los archivos css porque no los encuentra. Puedes mirar a ver si en el inspector de elementos, en el tab "consola" obtienes algún error 404.

Comment: Hola, sí, sí, las rutas son correctas y los estilos por separado los del componente y los de la web se cargan. A la hora de hacer el require es cuando fallan.

Comment: Por algún casual no tendrá el navegador el css cacheado y por eso no estas viendo cambios de css? Prueba a actualizar la página refrescando la cache ( en windows ctrl + f5 / en mac commad + shift + r

Comment: Eso era :O
Había apagado el ordenador para irme a comer y al volver todo seguía igual.
Pero he pulsado ctrl.+f5 y se han cargado los estilos.
Muchas gracias Ibai.

Answer (score 0):

Al final era un problema de caché.
Estaba desconcertado porque trabajo desde XAMPP y al escribir en mi navegador la ruta: localhost/mi_pagina/pages/home.php me cargaba la parte correspondiente al require sin estilos. Pero si desde Visual Studio Code en esa misma página hacía correr el PHP SERVER me funcionaba correctamente y cargando los estilos.
Al final, siguiendo el consejo del usuario Ibai A. pulsando ctrl.+f5 recargo la página borrando el contenido en caché y ha cargado los estilos correctamente.